# How to do Pivoting in Power BI using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the below table.

[image]

I want the resulting output like below.Is there a way using the DAX to get this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get this matrix visual with a very simple measure and setting the empname on the rows and the status on the columns like folows:

```
# Status = COUNTROWS( T )
```

[image: matrix visual]

Comment: Yes, @sergiom..Thanks..We can do this like in Matrix Visual by using the implicit measure...is there another way to do this like using explicit measures and using DAX expression by creating new measures or columns?

Comment: well, I did write an explicit measure in DAX, I didn't use implicit measures. I wonder if what you really think of is a DAX query to return a table, that's to say a calculated table.

Comment: This should not be marked as the accepted answer. OP asks for a `DAX` formula